# SQL Server query question (Count maybe?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  A.shipment_id
        ,B.box_id
        ,A.shipment_status
FROM shipments A
join boxes B on A.shipment_id = B.shipment_id
where A.shipment_status = 2
Group by B.box_id, A.shipment_id, A.shipment_status
```

That returns a result set that looks like this:

**shipment_id**, **box_id**, **shipment_status**
101, boxA, 2
101, boxB, 2
101, boxC, 2
102, box101, 2
102, box102, 2
103, boxA1, 2
103, boxA2, 2

I would like to return something like this instead (showing a total amount of boxes per shipment):

**shipment_id**, **box count**, **shipment_status**
101, 3, 2
102, 2, 2
103, 2, 2

How would I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  A.shipment_id
        ,COUNT(*) AS boxcount
        ,A.shipment_status
FROM shipments A
join boxes B on A.shipment_id = B.shipment_id
where A.shipment_status = 2
Group by A.shipment_id, A.shipment_status
```

Just need to remove the `box_id` from the `GROUP BY` and use `COUNT`, as you said in your title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  A.shipment_id
    , count(1)
    , A.shipment_status
  FROM shipments A
  join boxes B on A.shipment_id = B.shipment_id
 where A.shipment_status = 2
 Group by A.shipment_id, A.shipment_status
```